# Matching without replacement by id in R

Tags: r, match

In R, I can easily match unique identifiers using the match function:

```
match(c(1,2,3,4),c(2,3,4,1))
# [1] 4 1 2 3
```

When I try to match non-unique identifiers, I get the following result:

```
match(c(1,2,3,1),c(2,3,1,1))
# [1] 3 1 2 3
```

Is there a way to match the indices "without replacement", that is, each index appearing only once?

```
othermatch(c(1,2,3,1),c(2,3,1,1))
# [1] 3 1 2 4 # note the 4 where there was a 3 at the end
```

Comment: are you assuming the two vectors are permutations of each other? in other words, what would this give: `othermatch(c(1,1,1), c(1,1))`?

Comment: Yes, I assume they are permutations. I would expect `othermatch(c(1,1,1), c(1,1))` to give an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're looking for `pmatch`

```
 pmatch(c(1,2,3,1),c(2,3,1,1))
 #  [1] 3 1 2 4
```

Comment: I was just writing that. But note the result of `pmatch(c(1,1,1), c(1,1))`.

Comment: This is great! NA is a result for not matchable elements is fine.

Comment: @Roland, what should be the result of such a thing?  We could recycle if needed, but I'm not sure if that would make sense.

Comment: I don't believe there should be a different result. But the OP commented that he expected an error in this case.

Comment: @Roland, gotcha.  I think it was just in response to eddi's asking about odd cases

Answer (score 2):

A more naive approach -

```
library(data.table)

a <- data.table(p = c(1,2,3,1))
a[,indexa := .I]

b <- data.table(q = c(2,3,1,1))
b[,indexb := .I]

setkey(a,p)
setkey(b,q)

# since they are permutation, therefore cbinding the ordered vectors should return ab with ab[,p] = ab[,q]
ab <- cbind(a,b)
setkey(ab,indexa)
ab[,indexb]
#[1] 3 1 2 4
```

Comment: Do you mean data.matrix? I don't have any data.table.

Comment: data.tables are like lean data.frames, and very nice. http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html